# devexpress - how to enable buttons on disabled ButtonEdit

Tags: wpf, devexpress

I'm trying to make a ButtonEdit which will have `edit` button. Till this button is not clicked, I would like to set `IsEnabled = false` to whole ButtonEdit, but the problem is that this code disables also my `edit` button.

Is there a way to have ButtonEdit disabled with enabled buttons?

I have tried of course setting `IsEnabled = true` for my button explicity in xaml, but it does not work.

Comment: I can't clear recognize what you want

Comment: What if use 'IsTextEditable' setting

Comment: Right now I'm using it. But I have to style control right now to look like disabled.